# force c++ compiler to check returning value

Tags: c++, g++

In this example will be called deconstructor of nonexisting object. G++ version 5.3,  compiling with  -Werror .

```
vector<vector<float>> segfault()
{

}

int main()
{
    segfault();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile with the `-Werror` flag. It does without that flag because a non-returning function that is non-void is just a warning not an error.

Comment: `-Wall` adds a warning about missing a return statement; in conjunction with `-Werror`, that will be treated as an error, so the code won't compile.

Comment: **-Werror=return-type**
  working, thank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `gcc` and `clang` have the option `-Wreturn-type`.
It is turned on implicitly when using `-Wall`.
To make it is a compiler error, use `-Werror=return-type`.